# How to bypass and continue after getting HttpRequest error

Tags: asp.net

I've got the following code.  (I don't know if I'm capturing this right in terms of my goal...to log and continue on)

```
        // Create the atual Request instance
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(requestURI, data.Length);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 30000;

        try
        {
            requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            // get response
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (response)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    _requestError = true;
                    string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _requestError = true;
        }
```

The remote name could not be resolved: 'api10.aaa.com'
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api10.aaa.com'

```
Source Error:

Line 87:                     {
Line 88:                         if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
Line 89:                         {
Line 90:                             _requestError = true;
Line 91:                             string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
```

our global.asax ApplicationError picks up any errors in the stack.

**Now my problem:**  I purposely changed the Uri this time to be invalid so that I would get an error for testing purposes and added in the _requestError boo private field flag which I want to expose if there's ever an error during a request.  Because I want to test cases where the request fails.  If the request fails, I want to be able to log and move on...not stop.  Right now, it stops.  I want to be able to access the _requestError through a public property that I expose.  This code above is actually in a base request class.  In one of my code-behinds, I am using an instance of this class and the code above is called.  I want to be able to get a bool flag, the requestError if anything major happens becuause in the code behind I wnat to log it to some tables...not our log tables, but for some other stuff related to some business logic and a certian other object.  So my point is, I'm not able to get this code to not halt the runtime.  I want to continue after this error happens otherwise I will never get the chance to utilize my public property baed off _requestError.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the value being passed to the requestUri variable is "api10.aaa.com".

Try typing that into your browser and see what happens.  You need to set the requestUri to a valid uri, meaning one you can type into your browser and navigate to.

***added***

Possibly this would work if it were "http://api10.aaa.com"??

***added after comments and code modifications***

OK.  That makes sense,

Then I believe that what is happening is that the error is occurring at this line:

```
requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

If that is the case, then nothing else within the try block will execure because the exception jumps you straight into the Catch block.

So you'd have to either put a try/catch around that one line, or move all your other code to the "Finally" block.

Comment: No, I am purposely changing it to be an invalid Uri.  I want to then be able to bypass any errors when the request has problems such as a bad Uri and be able for the code behind class calling and using an instance of my class that contains this code will be able to grab  _requestError through a public property and do something with it.  Right now, if I get any errors (invalid URi or whatever the case may be), I get the thrown exception.  I want to essentially log it and move on.

Comment: my fault, I did not finish the damn initial thread.  Good God.  Read it now.